# Why does the Window-margin used in Designer, get smaller in the running Program?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, margin, designer

When using the Designer in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, and creating a simple Window with a textbox with 10p margin to the right and the bottom, the margin changes as soon I run the program.
How would i avoid this?

Example image: (I can't post images yet, so heres the bare link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCrXL.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUceC.jpg

Another image explaining it even better.

As you can see in the image above, the margin changes dramatically when running the program.

My Windows XAML Code is:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800" Focusable="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" UseLayoutRounding="False">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="351" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="774"/>
</Grid>
```

XAML Code of the other image:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800" Focusable="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" UseLayoutRounding="False">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="10,156,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="774"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="709,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="699,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added the XAMLCode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying a `Width` and `Height`, just specify a margin and allow it to stretch:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Note that you explicitly had margins of `10,10,0,0`, which mean you will only get margins on 2 sides - using a single number (`10`) or making all 4 numbers `10` puts an even margin all the way around.

---

Edit in response to your new version:

In this case, the better approach is to use the `Grid` layout features:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" />
  <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button" Margin="10" Width="75"/>
  <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="RadioButton" Margin="10" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: I do not want an actual stretched TextBox, this was just to explain the problem, my issue is, i often align items by the bottom/right margin "snap point" and some of those items just have fixed sizes, and need them.

Comment: @user2001803 Fixed sizes are problematic.  It's much better to use relative sizing and layout to control it....

Comment: Relative to your user's device. In fact, its considered a Best Practice to avoid using fixed postitions in favour of relatives entirely for wpf, as said by microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Layout

Comment: @user2001803 First you need to read on how to design layouts!

Comment: How is that related to my Margins disappearing and cutting controls width off? My window never changes its size, and the resolution will always be bigger than the window, so i don`t need relative sizes.

Comment: @user2001803 The window size itself is dependent on your theme, and that's not represented in the designer.  Essentially, the window **is** resized when run (compared to your design time experience).  Making everything layout based completely solves this (and lets it resize, too!)

Comment: Then the question is wrong, how do I let the window stay the same size, forcing it to enlarge in case its needed due to theme change?

Comment: Or is the only way to avoid this making the window 10p larger and giving the main grid 10 margin to bottom/right...